# 'You did not select a file to upload' codeigniter

Tags: php, html

I am trying to upload an image via codeigniter but constantly recieve the following message: 'You did not select a file to upload'.

I have viewed many SO answers on this but nothing has helped:

- PHP config max File upload size: 2M (I tested with 0.5mb files)
- Form is multipart
- Website is on localhost

HTML:

```
<h3>Upload profile image</h3>
    <div data-role="fieldcontainer">
        <form action='do_upload_prof' method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name='file'>
        <input type='submit' value='upload' />
        </form>
    </div>
```

PHP Controller:

```
public function do_upload_prof() { 
    $config = array(
        'upload_path' => "./profile_img/",
        'allowed_types' => "gif|jpg|png|jpeg",
        'overwrite' => TRUE,
        'max_size' => "4048000", 
        'max_height' => "768",
        'max_width' => "1024"
    );
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    if ($this->upload->do_upload('file')) {
        $data = array(
            'upload_data' => $this->upload->data()
        );
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('profile', $data);
        $this->load->view('footer');
    } else {
        $error = array(
            'error' => $this->upload->display_errors()
        );
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('profile', $error);
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show for us what you get var_dumping the $_FILES variable? Also try change your form to enctype="multipart/form-data;charset=utf-8"

Comment: @marceloch2 I dumped $_FILES["file"]["name"] and its empty. I also made you recommended change and no luck.

Comment: Sorry to ask again, but you var dumped the variable alone? like, var_dump($_FILES);

Comment: @marceloch2 Yes, the result was: array(0) { }

Comment: Also try to use the CI form shortcode to test.


<?php echo $error;?>

<?php echo form_open_multipart('upload/do_upload');?>
<input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" />
<input type="submit" value="upload" />
</form>

Comment: Another test i have in mind it to change for the default name in CI documentation, worth the try.

<input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" />

and use it in the do_upload function. Check the docs [link](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html#CI_Upload::do_upload), maybe help